# How to wrap a tag that was dynamically added with a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a tooltip component that works by wrapping around things users would hover.

```html
<MyTooltip
  :content="`This text will be shown in tooltip`"
>
  Hover over me to see tooltip
</MyTooltip>
```

1. I'd like to use the tooltip component to wrap `<a class="Bug"></a>` tag, Like this:

```html
<p>some 
<MyTooltip content="some content">
    <a class="link">Bug</a class="bug">bug 111</p> was found
</MyTooltip>
</p>
```

2. This `<a class="Bug"></a>` tag was dynamically added by doing regex match in `renderMsg`.

```html
<div @mouseover="onHover>
   <span
     v-html="renderMsg(msg)"
   />
</div>
```

```js
methods: {
  renderMsg(msg) {
    return txt.replace(some_regex_object, '<a class="bug">$&</a>');
  },
  onHover(e) {
    if (e.target.className === 'bug') {
      // tried adding `<MyTooltip content="some content">${e.target.outerText}</MyTooltip>` to DOM
    }
  },
},
```

So you see where the challenge is... I modified `<a class="Bug"></a>` to become `<MyTooltip><a class="Bug"></a></MyTooltip>` using dom manipulation interface (something like `parentNodeOfATag.replaceChild` with new dom element containing tooltip tag). `<MyTooltip>` was rendered as `<MyTooltip>` which has no meaning by itself.

Comment: Can you please also post the component's `props` and/or `data` part. This really requires more context, for example what is the root element of this tooltip component? The `div`? Better post the rest of the relevant code.

Comment: But one thing for sure, you should never manipulate the DOM with Vue, unless the dynamic elements are intentionally meant to be static and non-reactive.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't vue slots solve your problem? https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

It would be like:

```
<MyTooltip content="some content">
<slot />
</MyTooltip>
```

And you could dynamically add anything inside the Tooltip.